# how to associate received sms messages (via twilio) to specific user in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm making an app that sends text messages to a group of people and then people can respond to the text. I want to be able to record the response, know who sent it, and associate it with the user who sent the original message. I've gotten the sending working, and I've begun putting together receiving sms messages but i'm confused. If twilio sends a post request to my server with the from number and message, how will I know which of my users sent the original message?

what if two different users send a message to the same person around the same time? what's the best way to handle this? do I need a separate 'to' number for each of my users? seems like that would get quite expensive. also, if each user has multiple campaigns (messages), how would I associate a response to a specific campaign?

i'm building a rails app.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a different Twilio number for each contact a user sends to.  This will establish a unique mapping between the 2 mobile devices and a Twilio number.  This allows you to forward incoming messages sent to the Twilio number back to the appropriately mapped mobile phone.  You'll do the lookup on your mapping based on who the incoming message is From.

You won't need a Twilio number for every one of your users, but you will need a pool of numbers which is the maximum number of contacts a single person can make.

There is an article on Twilio's site which gives additional information:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio

Comment: Interesting. I'm still a little confused though. My users aren't sending text message from their own phone, they are sending it from my app, which I thought meant I needed to have the "from" number to be a twilio number. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that I need a separate twilio number for each "campaign" a user has. So let's say a campaign has 10 recipients, I have 1 unique number for that campaign. When a recipient replies, I can tie it back to that specific campaign and user based on the from/to numbers, right?

Comment: Also, how would that strategy work if users are sending text messages from a web app? Doesn't that mean they can't send from their own cell phone numbers?

Comment: Yes, the message needs to be sent 'From' a Twilio number.  Create a mapping between that Twilio number and the recipient's number and associate it to your local user.  Then when you get a reply to the Twilio number you can use the 'From' number (recipient) and 'To' number (Twilio number) to lookup the local user.  This means you do need a different Twilio number for each person your local user messages - for a 10 recipient campaign that's 10 Twilio numbers.  But you can reuse the Twilio numbers for other local users, provided they send to different recipients the mappings will remain unique.